# Pandas: How to resolve truth value of a Series is ambiguous

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to apply a function to a DataFrame but I keep receiving this error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

The line I am calling is this one:

```
 results['M1_Position'] = df.apply(instr_1(ratios, s_entry, s_exit))
```

and the function instr_1 is as follows:

```
def instr_1(ratio, s_entry, s_exit):
    if ratio > s_entry:
        return 1
    elif ratio < s_exit:
        return -1
    else: 
        return 0
```

I understand why the error arises, but I don't think that either a.all() or a.any() would be helpful in this situation. How do I apply the function to each row of my DataFrame separately, without using a for loop (I'd like to keep it vectorized)?

Comment: nevermind, I was able to resolve this using a lambda function

Comment: If your lambda function looks like the one in my answer, please consider marking it as accepted : it helps other people find answers later on.

Comment: lambda function is **not** vectorized. You should look for `np.select`. For example `np.select([df.ratio > df.s_entry, df.ratio < df.s_exit], (1,-1), 0)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming ratio, s_entry, and s_exit are columns of your dataframe:

```
 results['M1_Position'] = df.apply(lambda row: instr_1(row.ratio, row.s_entry, row.s_exit), axis=1)
```